# check condition in an array of characters and goto next steps if condition satisfies: iMacros

Tags: javascript, arrays, imacros

i am extracting some data from a website using the "EXTRACT" command, my result gives me alphanumeric results like "AL1,AL2,B1,B2,ALH1,BHD3". These results are usually anywhere between 1-4 characters long.

Now, i want to compare these extracted values with a bunch of values that i have in an array variable, and only if the extracted result matches with any of the value in the array variable, i want the iMacro to either do a certain steps or goto next macro and if it doesn't match, I want it to do another set of steps or goto another macro instead.

Can someone please help me with this? I have tried a few possibilities, but have horribly failed at it.

Many thanks in advance for all the help offered... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step to your workable solution may look like this:

```
SET bunch "A,AB,B1"
SET !EXTRACT "AL1,AL2,B1,B2,ALH1,BHD3"
SET match EVAL("var m = false; var b = '{{bunch}}'.split(/,/); var e = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.split(/,/); for (i in b) if (e.indexOf(b[i]) > -1) m = true; m;")
PROMPT {{match}}
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot buddy... it works perfect... now do i make it to perform certain steps if true and certain steps if false? :O Also, i would like to run it on a loop of extraction variables... :)

Comment: OK. I would recommend that you post a new question and provide more details about: (1) what next steps will be when the `match` variable is true and otherwise; (2) what browser(s) you intend to use; (3) how you'd like to set the number of loops etc. In this case some useful advices may appear :)